# How do I print a loop output iteration into a file?

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I'm trying to save a loop output into a text file with python. However, when I try to do so only the first line of the result gets printed on the file.

This is the line I want to print the result of:

```
with open('myfile.txt','w') as f_output:
       f_output.write(
           for k, v in mydic.items():
               print(f"{k:11}{v[0]}{v[1]:12}"))
```

This prints only the first line of the result.

My dict looks like this:

```
mydic = {'1': [22, 23], '2': [33,24], '3': [44,25]}
```

I need it to print this to the file:

```
1          22      23
2          33      24
3          44      25
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Note that `print(...)` is a function call that returns (evaluates to) None. I am not sure how this code ran, since the `for` block does not evaluate to something that can work as a parameter for a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write in append mode with `a`:

```py
mydic = {'1': [22, 23], '2': [33,24], '3': [44,25]}

with open('myfile.txt','a') as f_output:
    for k, v in mydic.items():
        # Also need `\n` for newlines:
        f_output.write(f"{k:11}{v[0]}{v[1]:12}\n")
```

Output:

```
1          22          23
2          33          24
3          44          25
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the argument from 'w' (write) to 'a' (append).

```py
mydic = {'1': [22, 23], '2': [33, 24], '3': [44, 25]}

with open('myfile.txt','a') as f_output:
    for k, v in mydic.items():
        res=f"{k:11}{v[0]}{v[1]:12}"
        f_output.write(f"{res}\n")
        print(res)
```